# How to translate into Russian a "Stolen From" label - украдено? ворованное?

Tags: перевод

If you want to label items so that in the event that someone steals one of them from you everyone will know where they got it from, in English you can write "Stolen From", e.g. "Stolen From Ruffle's Office".

How would you do this in Russian? Would you write "Ворованно", "Украдено", or something else? Would you decline for gender? Would you translate "from" as "из" "от", or "у"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's stolen from a person, then it will be, for instance, "украдено у Льва Петровича", if we are talking here about about a company or organization, "украдено из" would be correct (or, to sound less strict, would be with a higher probability more appropriate), like in "украдено из Петровского парка" or "Украдено из ООО "Амурские авиасистемы". The neuter form would be ok for gender-agnostic designation, one can say "украдена у Льва Петровича" however this would be very unnatural without the actual noun: "[эта] книга украдена у Льва Петровича".

However! While those phrases are technically correct nobody in Russia talks like that and use this particular form in sake of purposes you've mentioned. It'll be just "собственность Льва Петровича" / "cобственность Петровского парка" etc.

Comment: https://moya-moskva.livejournal.com/3609492.html

Comment: @Elena awesome finding! So it used to be that way but nowadays it's not a thing.

Answer (score 0):

Had we been using this wording in a serious vein, the optimal verb would have been "похищенo".

In reality, though, this wording is never used seriously. Still, I can imagine it being employed in a jocular vein -- in which case the verb should be downgraded to the sarcastic (and pretty vulgar) synonym "спизжено".

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сказал:

про краденные вещи: "стыбреные", "стыреные", "краденые", "ворованные"

про краденную информацию: "плагиат"